# Alert over Modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to show this alert on top of the Modal but unable to get it working. Instead, it shows behind the Modal.

The html:

```
    <alert class="alertmessage" ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">
            <small>{{alert.msg}}</small>
    </alert>
```

The CSS:

```
    .alertmessage {
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        width: 300px;
        margin-left: -150px;
        margin-top: -100px;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 99999 !important;
        outline: 9999px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        border-radius: 0px;
    }
```

The modal css goes like this:

```
    element.style {
        z-index: 1040;
        display: block;
    }
```

What am I missing? I want to see the alert coming on top of the Modal.

Comment: Chances are the containers each of these are in have different z-indexes that are overriding the child z-indexes.

Comment: There's no z-index greater than 1050 for the modal. I even tried z-index: 99999999999999999999999999999999999999 !important; for the .alertmessage class but that didn't help!! I can't see any override either. Hoping someone with experience in Bootstrap Modal could answer.

Comment: Z-indexes of children don't matter if a parent somewhere has a lower one than something else. For instance, if I have two divs A & B with indexes of 1 & 2, no matter what I put on a div inside A, it will always be beneath B because the parent container z-indexes will override. Please post all relevant HTML and CSS.

Comment: There is not must code to go on but still unable to re-produce the error http://jsfiddle.net/benxmf5y/ i remove the z-index and alert is still on top of modal

Comment: i'm using angularJS and cannot have the alert within the modal code since the alert is called globally. it still goes behind when i put the alert outside of modal:  http://jsfiddle.net/benxmf5y/1/

Answer (score 5):

Here's an updated Fiddle that's working for you.  http://jsfiddle.net/benxmf5y/5/

The only change I made was to add

```
z-index: 999999;
```

Comment: For some reason, it works here but not on my AngularJS! I added x-index initially. Anyways, I have removed the alert system and instead i'm throwing error on the modal itself in red color. Thank You so much :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try putting the alert code in a div inside the modal div itself and keep it hidden and then trigger the alert when needed.
If the alert is inside the modal then it will definitely come above the modal.

Comment: I meant put the alert message inside the modal code. It works for me, check the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/benxmf5y/3/

Comment: I'm using AngularJS and can't have it inside the modal code since i have to call the alert for non-modal error reports too. Also, when i try to use div on top of the alert, the entire website goes in overlay mode!! Looks like I'll have to figure out myself since I can't share the entire website :/

Answer (score 0):

The way I got it to work was by making sure that the Alert component was above everything by being placed in the index.js file, and making sure that the Alert was placed within a Portal component.

```js
import React from "react";
import Alert from "@mui/material/Alert";
import { Portal } from "@mui/material";

const portalStyle = {
  display: "grid",
  gridAutoFlow: "row",
  alignItems: "start",
  alignContent: "start",
  justifyContent: "end",
  justifyItems: "end",
  gap: "10px",
  width: "100%",
  height: "100%",
  position: "absolute",
  top: "50%",
  left: "50%",
  transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
  p: 4,
  borderRadius: "2px",
  outline: "none",
  pointerEvents: "none",
  userSelect: "none",
};

const alertStyle = {
  width: "100%",
  maxWidth: "650px",
  pointerEvents: "none",
  userSelect: "none",
};

const AlertModal = () => {
  return (
    <Portal>
      <div
        style={portalStyle}
      >
        <Alert
          sx={alertStyle}
          severity="info"
          variant="filled"
        >
          {alert.message}
        </Alert>
      </div>
    </Portal>
  );
};

export default AlertModal;
```